# How can i get the URN of an uploaded forge file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I followed this tutorial https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-aspnet-zero-hero-30-minutes and made a web application that can upload and view a model, but I cannot view an old model without uploading it again as I cannot save the URN of the file to send it to viewer again. So, how can I get and save the URN of the file to use it whenever I want to view the model without uploading it again?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information if you want your question answered, as nobody will be able go through that tutorial to find out how to help you. Talk in more detail about what you've done, and what mechanisms you have available to save that URN

Answer (score 1):

*Object ID* is typically retrieved using the [Data Management APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/), for example, when [listing contents of a bucket](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET).

*URN* is then obtained by base64-encoding the object ID. Here's an [example](https://github.com/petrbroz/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/OSSController.cs#L157-L161) of how you can base64-encode strings in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest to follow the new [Tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge). This will give you a better understanding of how things work. If you want to just have the urn of an uploaded model you can just log it into the console at a couple of points. The `showModel(urn)` function in ForgeViewer.js is a good place to do so for example.

Comment: Agreed, https://learnforge.autodesk.io provides a more complete tutorial, connecting all the byte-sized examples into a complete application.